# iPhone 4 not supporting in XCode 3.2

Tags: iphone, ios4, provisioning, xcode3.2

I am haivng an iPod which recently updated to iOS4.0. It is working fine with the device. I am having the XCode version 3.2 installed on my mac. When I try to test the apps on my device it displays an error.

```
No provisioned iPhone OS device is connected.
```

Is there any way to make it working.

Answer (score 0):

Is your iPod properly connected to your computer? Check in Xcode's Organizer (Window -> Organizer) to see if your device has a green dot next to it.

If it doesn't, just recheck that your device is registered with Apple.

developer.apple.com -> sign in -> provisioning portal -> devices